Trying to remember a movie about gremlin or similar
I'm not sure if this movie involved gremlin, but I remember that their size was similar. All I can remember is the ending where the protagonist had to kill his mother because she turned into a monster that breeds the gremlin-sized monster by splitting her stomach.
Sorry for the gore and vague explanation
EDIT
Year : Not sure when
Language : English
Country : US?maybe
Sorry, but no more plot details I can recall because I watched that movie when I was very young

The movie I was looking for was called "Dead Alive" (1992).
The way I remembered it was really off but the part about where the protagonist had to kill his beloved mother was correct

@ElDuderino I have to wait 2 days

So by 'gremlin' you meant the Sumatran Rat Monkey?

@Walt yeah, I'm suprised how I mistaken it for a gremlin
